# How to filter on date during data manipulation of text file?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, sqldf

I'm completing an assignment for coursera and need to create a subset of data with first 2 days of Feb 07.

Here's my code:

```
library(sqldf)

# set directory 
setwd("C:/Users/thoma/Desktop/Files/Programming/R/EDA/EDAWk1")

# unzip source data
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip", temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "household_power_consumption.txt"), header = TRUE, sep = ';')


# we only want a specified range of dates 
data_2 <- sqldf("
                select
                * 
                from data
                where Date in ('2007-02-01','2007-02-02')
                ")
```

The intermediate dataset 'data' is working fine, however I get null for data_2. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in base R :

```
data_2 <- subset(data, Date %in% as.Date(c('2007-02-01','2007-02-02')))
```

Or using `dplyr` and `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data_2 <- data %>% filter(month(Date) == 2 & day(Date) <= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works - wish I could understand why sqldf wouldnt work though

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[Date %in% as.IDate(c('2007-02-01','2007-02-02'))]
```